# IOException when running unit tests

Tags: .net, unit-testing

While running unit tests, getting the below error. Any cluess as to why this come?

```
System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path)
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.TestHostAdapter.DeviceAgent.DeviceSerializableTestContext.SetupTestFolders()
Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.DeviceHostAdapter.DHAServer.RunTest(String serializedUnitTestElement)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.DeviceHostAdapter.DHAServer.ExecuteCommand(Object obj)
System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
System.Threading.Timer.ring()
```

Comment: Did you start Visual Studio in Admin mode?

Comment: Yes, started in admin mode